# Detecting and cropping a face from an picture?

Tags: java, face-detection

I am working on a Face Recognition system for my internship. I am developing the project in Java right now. I am using OpenCV library, but it does not seem to work correctly in detecting faces.

I am at a point, where I capture image from the desktop and store it on the hard drive.

All I want now is to detect a face in that image (NOT IDENTIFY). I just need to detect that face and crop it.

Please help me with it. If anyone has specific code in Java to detect faces in a images, please send me that too.`72236`

Comment: I think you misunderstand the purpose of this site. 96135

Comment: See related posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182849/face-detection-in-java. The OpenCV wiki on Face Detection: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceDetection

Answer (score 1):

This [library](http://code.google.com/p/jjil/) already has face detection built in.  You'd probably be better off using it.

Comment: Well I tried using the library.. i am using opencv1.0 with java, but it does not seem to work.. initially it just gave me a blank screen.. I tried fixing that and later on the web cam runs but there is no face detection in it..